# HTML Editor with Java and And webkit - SWT Browser

Tags: java, webkit, swt, contenteditable

i want to add WYSIWYG HTML editor to my Java program.
my idea is to do Something like [this](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5.ars)
but not with python - with Java.

i know about couple of options and their problems :

- **HTMLEditorKit** - not sophisticated enough.
- **JWebpane** - fairy tale.
- **QtWebKit** - not open source.
- **JWebEngine** - not open source.
- **metaphaseeditor** - to simple.
- **The Lobo Project** - not support the contenteditable attribute.
- **JavaXPCOM** - I don't Succeed to operate it on my mac OS X 10.6.
  Anyway, I just prefer not to use it because Gecko is slower then webkit.

That's way I chose to work with 

**[Browser Object](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html)**  from *org.eclipse.swt.browser* Package.

For now, I have the code below:
The code, first create a instance of the browser object.
After this it's load HTML page with `contenteditable='true'` attributes on the body tag.
If its load a page its supposed to add `contenteditable='true'` attributes to the body tag, and when its save the page it's supposed remove it.

My questions are:

- How do I grab the edited HTML code?
- How do I know were the cursor is step on?
- How do I know if some text is highlighted?

**Or, in general :**

- How do I build a word possessor with Browser Object and ontenteditable='true' attributes?
- is it possible?
- is this the right way for WYSIWYG HTML editor in Java?
- Any Examples out there?
  I already check the SWT [Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser) - doesn't help much.

Thanks a lot.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class editor {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
   String html = "<html><title>Editor</title>"
       + "<body  contenteditable='true'>"
       + " <h2>All the Page is ditable!!!!!</h2>" 
       + "<p>Heres a typical paragraph element</p>" 
       + "<ol><li>and now a list</li>" 
       + "<li>with only</li>" 
       + "<li>three items</li>" 
       + "</ol></body></html>";
  Display display = new Display();
   Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  final Browser browser;
  try {
   browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.BORDER);
  }
  catch (SWTError e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   display.dispose();
   return;
  }
  Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
  comp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.ALL));

  browser.setText(html);
  shell.open();
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
   if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DJ Native Swing project has several HTML editors, implemented using the SWT Browser (this is an implementation detail): http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

Answer (score 1):

I like it that you asked some very specific questions! Good job brainstorming before you get your hands dirty.

Fortunately, there's a fairly generic solution to your problem: just [run JavaScript in the browser](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/BrowsermodifyDOMexecutingjavascript.htm).

For instance:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
// Just to be sure we can use JavaScript
browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
boolean result = browser.execute("alert('Hello SWT!')");
if (result) {
    System.out.println("script executed");
} else {
    System.err.println("script failed to execute");
}
```

Of course you might want to send data from the browser back to SWT; in this case you might end up in the worst case having to parse `browser.getText()`. I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment
and even more thanks for the reply!!!

It seems the right time to learn c/c++...

With these languages its should by much more appropriate for such things...

Answer (score 1):

Thy this one tinymc: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ 
It's well documented and you can integrate it into almost any existing code as it has a nice interface and lots of plugins.