# How to write SWT application that use tinyMCE?

Tags: java, tinymce, swt

I need write an application to import html data into database. The user can insert his document, then edit it, bold it, italick it and so on. And Then I need to insert HTML data into database.
So I want to write standalone application in java (swt) that use tinyMCE.
any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run TinyMCE by itself, it relies on having a full browser environment with JavaScript, ContentEditable, the whole works.

With recent developments you can try running WebKit in your app, and then TinyMCE inside that. I haven't seen any apps actually doing this, but there are a couple of options to experiment with:

- [JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/)
- [WebKit as the SWT Browser rendering engine](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit)

Or you could go with a pure Java HTML editor:

- [This SO question has a few open source options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107879/html-editor-with-java-and-and-webkit-swt-browser)
- [Commercial editor](http://editlive.com/) (disclaimer: I work for this company, there are [others](http://www.realobjects.com/products/edit-on-ng/))

Comment: can you say some cons of using webkit in java? Which one is powerfull: java webkit or python webkit? is it better to write my program in python with webkit?

Comment: The big drawback of using WebKit in Java will be doing it cross platform; JavaFX 2 is still only in pre-release for OS X. I can't speak for Java vs Python, I haven't used Python :)

Comment: Thank you Spyder. I have found Dj Project (Sweet) useful for Webkit in Java. this project implemented what I need, see this: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/screenshots/images/HTMLEditor.png

Answer (score 1):

Running TinyMce by it self is not possible.

But you can use a Browser component and give him a local html file to open with :

```
browser.setUrl(LOCAL_FILE_URL) ;
```

(LOCAL_FILE_URL is the url of your html file, something like : "file://[fullpath]/[yourfile].html"

In this html file, include TinyMce (look at their web site how to do this).
Always in this html page, add a javascript function to get the content of TinyMce generated html (the one you see when you click on the "Source code" in TinyMce). This function MUST RETURN a String containing the html formated text. Your function will be something like :

```
function getContent() {
    return tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
}
```

Now in your swt code ask the browser to execute the javascript function you've implemented using the evalute function.

```
String tinyMceEditedText = (String) browser.evalute("return your_javascript_function();");
```

With this line, tinyMceEditedText variable now contains the HTML entered but the user.
Works perfectly for me: Formated html can be saved in a database and bring back in TynyMce or formated in swt text.

Hope it'll help someone out there.

Regards